# Unable to set full-text index to 'active' in table-designer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

In SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio, I have set my database to be full-text indexed and ran the command

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
```

along with creating a catalog. When I open the table design mode, and right click the `Primary Key`, then click `Full-Text Indexes` in the context menu, I add my columns under the 'General' section, but when I go to set it to Active = Yes, it's grayed out.

How can I change this?  Here is a screen-shot of what it's looking like.

http://snag.gy/2QSDN.jpg
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you can't enable or disable the full text index from that screen. Instead you have to right-click the table in Object Explorer, then choose **Full-Text index > Enable Full-Text index**.

[image: screenshot]